# Find all subspaces of a three-dimensional spacethat are invariant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find all subspaces of a three-dimensional space that are invariant simultaneously with respect to two linear transformations defined by matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  5& -1& -1\\
  -1& 5& -1\\           
-1&   -1& 5
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  6& 2& 3\\
  2& -3& 6&\\           
3&   6& 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

I don't know where to start

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question?

Comment: Let's start here.... what does "invariant" mean in this question?

Comment: it means that  $$ {   }T(W) \subseteq W $$
where 
W -  the desired subset. 
T - one of our matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two observations will help tackle this problem

1. If you have an eigenvector $v$ for a transformation $T$, consider the vector space of $W = k v$. This is invariant under the transformation $T$
2. For a symmetric matrix, there exists $n$ eigenvectors that are mutually orthogonal corresponding to each eigenvalue

Using these two facts, the problem is apparent - find the intersection of the two eigenspaces for each of the transformations